# Calculating YoY revenue when not all accounts existed last year

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to calculate YoY revenue in Snowflake. I have 3 columns: account_id, activity_date, and arr. I've tried using a CTE to calculate, but the problem I have is that the account id's from today, might not all be the same from a year ago. I am trying to calculate this for each and every day and account. Here's what I have:

```
WITH CTE AS(SELECT account_id, account_name, activity_date, arr
                     FROM arr_base)
          SELECT c1.*, c2.arr AS yoy_arr
          FROM CTE c1
          LEFT JOIN CTE c2 ON c1.account_id = c2.account_id AND c2.activity_date = dateadd(year, -1, c1.activity_date)
```

This approach ends up excluding some records, because not all accounts match. So the yoy_arr value is smaller than it should be. Any suggestions?

Edited to add sample data, current results and desired results:

Sample Data:

| Account_ID | Activity_Date | ARR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jan. 31, 2021 | 50 |
| B | Jan. 31, 2021 | 40 |
| A | Jan. 31, 2020 | 40 |
| B | Jan. 31, 2020 | 35 |
| C | Jan. 31, 2020 | 30 |
| D | Jan. 31, 2020 | 30 |

Current Results:

| Account_ID | Activity_Date | ARR | YOY_ARR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jan. 31, 2021 | 50 | 40 |
| B | Jan. 31, 2021 | 40 | 35 |

Desired Results:

| Account_ID | Activity_Date | ARR | YOY_ARR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jan. 31, 2021 | 50 | 40 |
| B | Jan. 31, 2021 | 40 | 35 |
| NULL | Jan. 31, 2021 | NULL | 60 |

Comment: Nothing should be excluded.  You have a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Please include sample data and desired results. Explain how the current query results differ from the desired results.

Comment: The problem I have is that when I sum up arr across all accounts, yoy_arr is smaller than it should be. Because some accounts from last year don't exist today. So the totals are wrong. Not sure if there is another way I can go about doing this where I can have it at account and date level, but still have totals be correct.

Comment: Please provide the information @FelipeHoffa requested. Just saying that a value is wrong without explaining what the value is, why it is wrong and what you think it should be doesn't help anyone to help you

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, and my apologies for not being clear enough. I've edited my post to include sample data, current results and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an common Business Intelligence Challenge:

The solution to prevent having to do these calculations is usually to create a fact table.

In the fact table, one would persist every date for every account and be able to do quick yoy comparisons and there would be no missing values to content with.

you table would have records like

accountid, year, arr
C, 2019, 0
C, 2020, 30
C, 2021, 0

To give you a direct solution vs recommended strategy see the code [here](https://gist.github.com/umjohndacosta/784d5fa7a41a5e50066d925c92696c22)

```
create or replace table arr_base(account_id varchar, account_name varchar, activity_date date, arr number(32,4));


insert into arr_base (account_id, account_name, activity_date, arr)
values
 ('A','ACCOUNT A','2021-01-31',50)
,('B','ACCOUNT B','2021-01-31',40)
,('A','ACCOUNT A','2020-01-31',40)
,('B','ACCOUNT B','2020-01-31', 35)
,('C','ACCOUNT C','2020-01-31', 30)
,('D','ACCOUNT D','2020-01-31', 30)
;




set start_date = '2018-01-01'::timestamp_ltz;
set end_date  = current_date();
set years = (select datediff(years,$start_date, $end_date) +1 );
  
with cte_accounts as (select distinct account_id, account_name from arr_base where activity_date between $start_date and $end_date )
,cte_dates as (select distinct year(activity_Date) as activity_year, activity_Date from arr_base where activity_date between $start_date and $end_date)
,cte_years as ( select seq4() + year($start_date) as txn_year from table(generator(rowcount=> $years)))
,cte_arr as (select account_id, account_name, year(activity_date) as activity_year, SUM( arr) as arr  from arr_base  where activity_date between $start_date and $end_date  group by account_id, account_name, year(activity_date)) 

-- cartesian product
select
dim.activity_year
,dim.account_id
,dim.account_name
,f1.arr as arr_current_year
,f2.arr as arr_next_year
,case when f2.arr is not null and f1.arr is not null then ((f2.arr - f1.arr) / f1.arr) else null end as yoy_arr
from 
(
select 
a.account_id
,a.account_name
,d.activity_year
from 
cte_accounts a cross join
cte_dates d 
) as dim left outer join 
cte_arr  as f1 on dim.account_id = f1.account_id and dim.activity_year = f1.activity_year left outer join 
cte_arr  as f2 on dim.account_id = f2.account_id and (dim.activity_year+1) = f2.activity_year
order by dim.activity_year
,dim.account_id
;
```

See Results Below:

[image]

https://gist.github.com/umjohndacosta/784d5fa7a41a5e50066d925c92696c22

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I'm going to play around with this a bit. If I can modify it to return ARR_PREVIOUS_YEAR rather than ARR_NEXT_YEAR, then this will be perfect for me.

Comment: With some small modifications to get ARR_PREVIOUS_YEAR and return results at the daily level, this worked perfectly for me. Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

I agree with you, that having the fact table you described would have been ideal.

Comment: awesome, glad this was of use to you.

Comment: if you are doing yoy on a daily basis, depending on your need, you can get skewed results if what you are using relies on day of the week. e.g. need to compare similar days. if you need to do like days comparisons like what are used in retail, you should look into creating a like-days calendar. check this out https://nrf.com/resources/4-5-4-calendar

Comment: ibm community has retail calendar in csv https://community.ibm.com/accelerators/catalog/content/Retail-4-5-4-calendar

Comment: Thanks for the additional details and advice! For this particular analysis, we are not taking day of week into consideration

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach adding onto John's excellent answer:-)

```
select  
       * 
from 
     (select  
         account_name
       , year(ACTIVITY_DATE) year_arr 
       , to_char(ACTIVITY_DATE,'DD-MON') arr_date,arr 
     from arr_base ) 
 pivot
    ( sum(arr) for year_arr in ('2021','2020' ))
```

[image]

```
create or replace table arr_base(account_id varchar, account_name varchar, activity_date date, arr number(32,4));


insert into arr_base (account_id, account_name, activity_date, arr)
 values
 ('A','ACCOUNT A','2021-01-31',50)
 ,('B','ACCOUNT B','2021-01-31',40)
 ,('A','ACCOUNT A','2020-01-31',40)
 ,('B','ACCOUNT B','2020-01-31', 35)
 ,('C','ACCOUNT C','2020-01-31', 30)
 ,('D','ACCOUNT D','2020-01-31', 30)
 ;


 select  p.* from (select  account_name, year(ACTIVITY_DATE) year_arr , to_char(ACTIVITY_DATE,'DD-MON') arr_date,arr from arr_base ) 
  pivot(sum(arr) for year_arr in ('2021', '2020' )) as p
```